# Infinite series for $n^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a simple infinite sum representation for $a^x$?  I can find $e^x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$ and plug in $x = xln(a)$ but I'm wondering if there's something out there that doesn't require the logarithm like that.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to represent it as a summation... exactly what sort of form are you looking for? Just anything without the logarithm?

Comment: ...I do not entirely follow, but if you're asking for a series $a^x$ for fixed $a$, then assuming $a > 0$ you can observe that $a^x = e^{x\ln(a)}$, which does give an infinite series in powers of $x$, with coefficients depending on $a$. To wit, we will have $a^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(a)^n x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: @Myridium -- pretty much.

Comment: @Chris -- Ahh, yes, that's what I meant by plugging in x=ln(n) but I'm wondering if there is anything that doesn't use the logarithm.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you represent $e^x$ using sum(Taylor polynomial centered at $x=0$) we can represent $\ln(x)$ using sum(this time Taylor polynomial centered $x=1$) to get to the formula:$$a^x=\sum_n\frac{\left(\sum\limits_m \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}(a-1)^{m+1}\right)^nx^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Btw, this sum does not converge for all $a$, you can find on the internet other sums that works for more values of $a$ and just replace this sum with what you find, I used this one because it is the simplest

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm is not a very big complication, it is just a constant. Maybe this is more clear notation-wise if you consider $a^{x}$ instead of $n^{x}$ or if you use a different letter for the index of the sum.

I think that the short/reasonable answer is no: if you compute the first terms of the Taylor series expansion around $0$ you will see that the constant $\log(a)$ pops up immediately.

Comment: I edited my answer to use a different index to be more clear, thank you.  However, I am still interested in something without the logarithm, or if there is a clear way to expand the log out into a double sum?

Comment: Yes, I guess you can expand every $\log(a)$ constant to a new infinite series in terms of elementary expressions by using the series representation of the logarithm function, which you can directly find on google (I don't know how to include links in comments, sorry)

Comment: @Pedro to include link in comment you just paste the link like this: [what is shown in the comment](http...)

Comment: It's cool, I got it [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) --- I was thinking of the crazy continued fraction. Maybe there's another series in there a little easier to work with.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question sounds like knowing that $f(x) = \sum a_nx^n$ then asking whether $f(\lambda x)= \sum \lambda^n a_n x^n$ can be represented as *another* series $\sum b_n x^n$ where $b_n$ somehow do not depend on $\lambda$.

The answer is negative, because of the uniqueness of the [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Analytic_functions) for an analytic function, which implies that $b_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \lambda^n a_n$.

Comment: Well, it's not that I'm trying to get rid fo the logarithm altogether, I'm just trying to represent the series in a simpler form that is easy to grep kind of.

Comment: @DavidNoll Point of my answer was that the power series in $\,x\,$ is unique regardless of how you write it. If you consider obfuscating the $\lambda = \ln(a)\,$ constant under a nested series as `a simpler form that is easy to grep` then that's your choice, but it wasn't obvious from the question as posed.

Comment: Yeah, I probably wasn't very clear.  Thanks for taking the time to answer